# How to return query set in SerializerMethodField in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

if I have SerializerMethodField and I wants to return query set. I tried to do this but doesn’t work

```py
 available_times = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_available_times(self, obj):
        qs = AvailableTimes.objects.filter(hall__id=obj.id)
        serializer = AvailableTimesSerializer(qs, read_only=True ,many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

it not working... give and Error.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `AvailableTimesSerializer`.

Comment: I solve the problem, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the method you want to use for that field, so it doesn't work, just add it:

```
available_times = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_available_times')
```

Comment: NO, I Solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

if your output Serializers.ModelSerializer  returns a queryset, you will need to serialize the queryset before returning it. Take a look at this sample

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Album 
        # fields = ['id','album_name','artist','release_date',]
        fields = ['id','album_name','artist','release_date','tracks']

    
   

    def get_tracks(self, obj):
        tracks= obj.track_set.all()
        serialized=TrackSerializer(tracks, many=True)
        return serialized.data
```

The foreign model track does not exist as a field in model album, but I was able to retrieve it  using the obj.track_set.all() which returns a queryset. The system will throw and error if I just return the queryset (tracks). I need to serialized it and send the serialized data back.